# How to start rails console on my ubuntu server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, linux, ubuntu, rubygems

I'm debugging an issue with a rails app on my ubuntu server and i'm trying to start the rails console to run a command, but this is what happens when I try to start the console:

```
myuser@rails-server1:/var/www/myapp/current$ rails c
The program 'rails' can be found in the following packages:
 * ruby-railties-3.2
 * ruby-railties-4.0
Try: sudo apt-get install <selected package>
```

Rails is definitely installed because my app is running and the gem is installed in this dir:

```
/var/www/myapp/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems
```

So how can i actually start the rails console?

Comment: how did you install rails?

Answer (score 7):

`bundle exec` to the rescue:

```
$ bundle exec rails console
```

Comment: I should probably add that you will need to run that command from your Rails application folder on your Ubuntu server

Answer (score 1):

I had this same issue once. 
In my case it had to do with RVM.

Add this to your ~/.bashrc

```
# This loads RVM into a shell session.
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && . "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"
```

This loads rvm each time you load a new terminal session.

Comment: Should this work, then you should be able to load the console as normal ("rails c").

Answer (score 1):

First, let's discover how did you install Ruby: by **apt-get**, **rvm** or **rbenv**:

open a shell and type this

```
# type rbenv | head -1
# type rvm | head -1
```

each command will return a **"xxx is a function"** or a **"-bash: type: xxx: not found"** (where "xxx" is "rbenv" or "rvm").

**"xxx is a function"** means that you had installed via **xxx** method.

If both commands returns "xxx: not found", then you had installed via apt-get and you will need to re-install via rbenv or rvm.

Now that you know what manager you had use, let's try to fix the problem.

If you installed via **RVM**, try this:

```
# \curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s -- --ignore-dotfiles
# echo "source $HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" >> ~/.bash_profile
```

If you installed via **RBENV**, try this:

```
# echo 'export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bashrc
```

Close the terminal, re-open and try again your "rails c"

PS: If nothing of this works, try to install another manager (if you are using RVM, try to install via RBENV, and vice-versa).

Answer (score 1):

looks likes `rails` isn't in your path, so you will need to specify a path to it (and generally speaking `.` isn't in your path on any sanely configured *nix box)

so try this  in `/var/www/myapp/current`

```
RAILS_ENV=production ./bin/rails console
```

That should get you a console using the version of rails that was installed in your bundle and get you into the correct environment.

Answer (score 1):

Better would be to use bundler when running rails specific command as

"bundle exec RAILS_TASK" like in these case "bundle exec rails s". When using bundler, it will find executable file in their GEM_PATH which is set during installation of ruby.